# Copying data from S3 to Redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, navicat

I feel like this should be a lot easier than it's been on me.

```
copy table
from 's3://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/filename.csv'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=my-access;aws_secret_access_key=my-secret'
REGION 'us-west-1';
```

Note I added the REGION section after having a problem but did nothing.

Where I am confused though is that in the bucket properties there is only the https://path/to/the/file.csv. I can only assume that all the documentation that I have read calling for the path to start with s3://... that I would just change https to s3 like shown in my example.

However I get this error:

```
"Error : ERROR:  S3ServiceException:
The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. 
Please send all future requests to this endpoint.,Status 301,Error PermanentRedirect,Rid"
```

I am using navicat for PostgreSQL to connect to Redshift and Im running on a mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The S3 path should be 's3://bucketname/filename.csv'. Try this.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what needs to be used...I was expecting needing to provide more than just the bucket name.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It should be a lot easier :-)

I have only seen this error when your S3 bucket is not in US Standard. In such cases you need to use endpoint based address e.g. http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/myfile.txt.

You can find the endpoints for your region in this documentation page,
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

Comment: Thanks for the answer.